# Geopandas for world map plotting from CSV files

Tags: geopandas

```
df = gpd.read_file("world-polygon.shp")

df.head()

df = df(['Country', 'Confirmed'])

data_for_map = df.rename(index=str, columns={'Country':'Regions','Confirmed':'Conf'})

data_for_map.head()
```

It gives me the error

```
TypeError: 'GeoDataFrame' object is not callable
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzz2U.png)

[This image is of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzz2U.png)

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace

```
df = df(['Country', 'Confirmed'])
```

by

```
df = df[['Country', 'Confirmed']]
```